# Google Sheets - Formula or Code?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

I'm needing a formula or code that will allow the following to happen if possible.

- First search column C for a value (Wk1,Wk2,Wk3,Wk4 or Wk5)
- then show the sum of column O In cell X15
- the formula should only sum the column up to the point Wk 2 shows in Column C

Something to note is that Column C will have a dropdown menu in each cell so the user can select when Wk1 or Wk2 etc starts so these values can move around rather than being a fixed distance apart.

Hope this makes sense and the sample image shows but if not please let me know and I'll do my best to explain further.

Thanks in advance.

[Link to Spreadsheet sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUT5C.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168734/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear cells `W13:Y100` and put this formula in cell `W13`:

```
=scan( 
  "Fill down", C13:C, 
  lambda( 
    previous, current, 
    if( 
      row(current) > max( index(row(O13:O) * (O13:O <> "")) ), 
      iferror(1/0), 
      if( len(current), current, previous ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

...and this formula in cell `X13`:

```
=query( 
  O13:W, 
  "select lower(W), sum(O) 
   where W is not null 
   group by lower(W) 
   label lower(W) '', sum(O) 'Sales' ", 
  0 
)
```

...to get results like these:

|  | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| wk1 | 3 |
| wk2 | 7 |
| wk3 | 5 |

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much - You have saved the day. :-)

Comment: Think i'm being a bit thick here but what would i need to do to the formula so as to move the results. The reason being as I was trying to duplicate it next to the results of this but amend it so that it picks up repairs only and then again for revenue but when i move it the formula stops working and nothing i do seems to rectify it?

Comment: To refer to some other columns, you need to modify column references in the `query()` statement. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if necessary.