# amending query statement difficulties

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

doubleunary kindly helped with the linked question however i'm struggling to amend the Query() section so as to pull different results. ie. for repairs and revenue also.

[Google Sheets - Formula or Code?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168734/google-sheets-formula-or-code/168736?noredirect=1#comment155631_168736)

I amended as per below but i'm getting the #Value error so quite obviously did this wrong

=query(    R13:W,    "select lower(W), sum(r)     where W is not null     group by lower(W)     label lower(W) '', sum(r) 'Repairs' ",    0  )

The linked image below should help with explaining what i mean, any questions please ask.

[image: Image of sample spreadsheet]

Comment: Please do not paraphrase errors but quote verbatim the exact error message you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column labels are case-sensitive in a query statement so `sum(r)` will not work. Further, in your sample spreadsheet, the number of repairs is not in column `R` but in column `Q`. Your use of merged cells is making that hard to see. Use this formula:

```
=query( 
  Q13:W20, 
  "select lower(W), sum(Q) 
   where W is not null 
   group by lower(W) 
   label lower(W) '', sum(Q) 'Repairs' ", 
  0 
)
```

Comment: I'm getting the below error: Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC

Comment: I'm trying to use the W column for the Weeks and moved the query formula to column AA, is this wrong or does the original part need to change also?

Comment: The error message indicates that column `R` does not contain numbers. Perhaps it contains text strings that look like numbers, or mostly nulls and very sparse numeric data. You can check the data with the `isnumber()` function. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: I believe this should be a link to a copy of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G1Z8OleM8M0cZlW81yioT4Itu9dNOW-w7nxW7O2Ujcg/edit?pli=1#gid=74953246

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help and apologies for the confusion with the merged cells. The new answer has cleared things up and allowed me to do what was needed.